# Completar un formulario vía Postman

Tags: post, postman

Necesitaría saber cómo puedo completar un formulario de cualquier página web en Postman, ya que al ingresar los parámetros correctamente no me funciona.

Lo que hago es elegir método Post, copio la URL donde se encuentran el formulario ej HTTPS://prueba.com/form y los parámetros los ingreso obviamente mediante los name

Gracias

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).